# ios change tableviewcell inside at scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and a `UIScrollView`. The scroll view is **paged**. In my table view, there is an image and a title (Custom Cell).

I want to change the image of the cell at any `index` according to the scroll views page, for example if the scroll view page is 4, the 4th cell's image will change (active coloured image), when I make the scroll view page 5, the 4th image will become normal (passive coloured image) and the 5th cell's image will change (active coloured image).

I want to change the images during `scrollViewDidScroll`. I could not find any possible solutions on internet. Is there a way to do this?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // how do i get page number : 0-768-1536 ---->0 means page1, 768 page 2 ...
    float currentPos = myScroller.contentOffset.x;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {

return konuBaslikListesi.count;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
return 90;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

KonularCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"KonularCell"];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KonularCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}

cell.Konuismi.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.Konuismi setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

cell.Konuismi.text=[[[konuBaslikListesi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     objectForKey:@"konu"] objectForKey:@"text"];

cell.imgKonuisaret.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menupassive.png"];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the page number from the size of each page and the content offset of the scroll view. The page number should be stored in a property.

```
CGFloat oldPage = self.page;

CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

CGFloat page = floorf(offset / pageWidth);

if (page != oldPage) {
    self.page = page;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then in your table view method (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) you would have something like:

```
if (self.page == indexPath.row) {
    cell.imgKonuisaret.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuactive.png"];
} else {
    cell.imgKonuisaret.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menupassive.png"];
}
```

Comment: i already know page number. you don't understand the question

Comment: Once you know the page you update your model to reflect the 'current' image and then `reloadData` on the table view.

Comment: i do not know how to change image at this index of table view

Comment: Edit the question to show your table view delegate / data source code.